# On facebook what is "Choose whether to post as yourself or as one of the Pages you manage."

Tags: facebook, social-media

I created a persona page on facebook. I don't want to show the posts on my persona on my personal profile page in facebook. So I'm a bit confused about the option of how to manage this post on my persona page. I apprciate any suggestion on this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question; please consult Facebook’s Help section for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create facebook company or fan pages you are able to switch between your personal profile or your company page's profile.

So, if I had a facebook page for my cookie store called Grandma's Cookies, I would have the ability to post as "Grandma's Cookies", or I can just post as "Layton."

Comment: Does that mean if you post as "Laydon" no one on seeing Grandma's Cookied would see it? I want to keep my busines page or persona page from views on my facebook profile page. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you posted as "Layton" on "Grandma's Cookies" page, then depending on your company page configuration, It would appear as a user posting on the companies page.

Comment: I understand that part about where you'd be posting from. I guess what I I want to find out is how to prevent your company postings from appearing on your personal profile pages. That's because, in my case, my company page or business page, is all about a persona or branding that can take on a life of its own that is not really about me. I'm taking a course in social media in which we create a persona or brand on social media. Since social media is more popular on mobile and tablet devices, programmers might take heed of this media in regards to how to better address their customers needs.

Comment: Make sure you are not following your persona account. I would have used a separate FB account all together.